# Perl Regex To convert String to Hex Warns of uninitialized value or to use /x

Tags: regex, perl, perl-critic

I am using regex in perl to convert string to hex, however, when I do this, I get a warning from either perl critic or perl:

```
#$test is defined, i just put the regex code snippet here...
#this will trigger a warning from perl critic
#warning: use of regex expression without "/x" expression..
$text =~  s/(.)/sprintf("%x",ord($1))/eg;

#this will trigger a a warning at run time 
#warning: "uninitialized value $1 in regexp compilation"
$text =~   m{s/(.)/sprintf("%x",ord($1))/eg}x;
```

Is there a way to write the above code that doesn't get a warning or feedback from Perl critic?

I think the issue is because ord is handling the undefined values, and when you put in /x then checking of the regex expression thinks that the value of $1 is invalid .

Comment: There is a built-in called hex that might suit your purposes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This critic is what is called a false positive. There's no need or reason for `/x` here. If you try to silence every critic, you'll end up with weird code. That said, the critic was recommending

```
s/(.)/sprintf("%x",ord($1))/exg
```

Furthermore, it probably makes no sense to avoid converting newlines. If so, you want to use `/s` too.

```
s/(.)/sprintf("%x",ord($1))/sexg
```

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why you wrapped the whole thing in m{...}x.. that completely changed the meaning.

Comment: Can you point me to where I can read more about what the /x is doing here (/what the parameters are there) ? [link]http://search.cpan.org/dist/Perl-Critic/lib/Perl/Critic/Policy/RegularExpressions/RequireExtendedFormatting.pm is why i put the m{}x . In any case putting the /x clears the perl critic error and runs error free(so I don't think this was a false positive) !

Comment: `/x` allows you to include whitespace and comments in the pattern. See [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html). The critic is trying to promote making your regex readable. The example shows how to add `/x` to `m//`, but you're not using `m//`. You're suppose to be adding `/x`, not switching to `m//`.